# Show all systemd services which are enabled, but not running

Tags: systemd

How can I show all systemd services which are enabled, but not running?

AFAIK "not running" can happen in two cases:

1. the service has crashed
2. the serivce was stopped.

In my current case I it does not matter if the services has crashed or it was explicitly stopped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this command :

```
systemctl list-units [-all] [--state=xxx]
```

I think this two commands show what you want to see :

```
systemctl list-units -all --state=inactive
systemctl list-units -all --state=failed
```

For more detailed explanations, you can refer to this answer :

https://superuser.com/questions/896812/all-systemd-states

Have a nice day.

Comment: I guess I will take the inverse, since there are more states than I initially thought. I query for all services which are not in state "active". Thank you for the link to the supeuser question.

Answer (score 2):

(I guess the o.p. has been doing what he wanted to do a long time ago, but for others searching for this)

MathieuR's answer pointed me in the right direction, but I found the best way (for me at least) to be

```
systemctl list-units -all | grep -Ev 'loaded  +active'
```

i.e. list all units except those with lines containing loaded followed by at least two spaces and then active.

Comment: Just wanted to hop on here and say this is a fantastic little one-liner! Saved!

Answer (score 1):

I found the existing answers interesting, but somehow I'm not a machine and don't want to search hundred lines of output and make my eyes bleed.

Coming from Gentoo/open-rc, I was really missing the `rc-status` command on Centos 8.
So I've made a one-liner, you just have to add an alias to your `~/.bashrc`.

```
for i in $(cd /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants && ls *.service); do script -q -c "systemctl status -n 0 --no-pager $i" |head -n 1; script -q -c "systemctl status -n 0 --no-pager $i" |grep --color=never "Active: "; done;
```

This show all enabled services and print their status on next line.
If you use a colored terminal, you will easily spot the inactive ones.